# How do I put context without Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

I want to navigate to next page which is FinalCart but there is no context in this page. When user click Book Now it will navigate to another page and will get the data from the details like price and calculate it.

```
Widget buildDetailsBottomBar(
     Map petspace,
      Color defaultColor,
      Color secondColor,
      Size size,
      //context 
    ) 
    {
            InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FinalCart),), //('book now'), //TODO: add book now action
              child: Container(
                width: size.width * 0.35,
                height: size.height * 0.07,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: defaultColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Align(
                  child: Text(
                    'Book Now',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      color: secondColor,
                      fontSize: size.height * 0.02,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: either pass it as a paremeter to use in your widget or use state-management solutions like getx

Answer (score 1):

I get the idea of defining a widget like that inside another widget, but, if you need to pass the current context just create it into a new **StatelessWidget**. Consider this also as a good practice because it can be built as a constant widget, preventing that it rebuilds over an over again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Widget buildDetailsBottomBar(
     Map petspace,
      Color defaultColor,
      Color secondColor,
      Size size,
      BuildContext context,
    )
```

as your widget parameters, then you can pass in the BuildContext of a widget that has one down to yours.

Comment: ` buildDetailsBottomBar(petspace, defaultColor, secondColor, size, context),`

there is problem in another page. i tried add context but still error